# Слушать пластинки?

Tags: перевод, значения

I heard the phrase while listening songs.

... Я буду ждать лишь твоей улыбки,
    И буду слушать твои пластинки ...

- макsим, ветром стать

... Твои пластинки слушала я 
    И в кождой находила себя ...

- винтаж, ева

I searched пластинки in dictionary and found out it means plate, layer. 
Well, I don't get the meaning :(

Comment: Charming choice of songs.

Answer (score 13):

In this context, the word refers to vinyl records.

Comment: And nowadays it can refer to CDs, too.

Comment: @Yellow Sky hardly, CDs would be диски

Comment: @Anixx - I know whot I write. [Proof1](http://tmborags.ru/?p=733), [proof2](http://rockyou.kiev.ua/news/item-12794.html), [proof3](http://megalyrics.ru/posts/music/2013-02-22-elton-dzhon-zapisal-no).

Comment: @YellowSky And all of them have vinyl versions. Also consider argot use, like _карточка_ for a photo.

Comment: @jwalker - Do you mean, those sites are devoted only to vinyl versions? I'm sure all those albums have audio DVD versions, too, so what?. I've seen it often on Russian TV when they show a CD and say, 'Группа Х выпустила свою дебютную пластинку.' I'm sure, those Russian one-album-issued-and-disbanded outfits never issue vinyl versions, sill their CDs, even EPs, are often called 'пластинка'.

Comment: @YellowSky The fact that all of them are released on vinyl might well be just a coincidence, but it certainly affects the value of such proof. Obviously a discussion like this wouldn't happen if _пластинка_ for a _CD_ were actually in wide use. So I suggested the likely argot theory, but if that's the case, you should have mentioned in your original comment that this use is special.

Comment: @jwalker - I did write 'It _can_ refer', which means 'can or cannot'. Note also the etymology of the English 'fan' (electric now, but made of feathers or paper in the 18th century), or 'dial a phone number' is still used although phones don't have any dials now, technology changes but the word persists.

Comment: One of the sites YellowSky refers to (megalyrics.ru) seems to use "пластинки" as a synonym to "альбомы". For instance, [here](http://megalyrics.ru/posts/music/2014-12-15-billboard-10-luchshikh-a) they cite billboard's [article](http://www.billboard.com/articles/events/year-in-music-2014/6405566/10-best-albums-of-2014) where authors complain that it's hard to pick only 10 best albums from all the albums released in 2014. Billboard does not mention 'vinyl' on their page, however пластинка is used on the Russian page. It's kind of slang, however modern song writers can also use the slang meaning.

Comment: Борис Гребенщиков is known to use 'пластинка' for a CD, therefore it is correct usage.

Answer (score 1):

In our language (Russian) "пластинки" means vinyl records only. CDs are "диски".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it means vinyl (here it may just mean any records). See why they are пластинки:

- [Апрелевский_завод_грампластинок](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA)
- [Грампластинка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0)